# .vue files not compiling as expected

Tags: vue.js, babeljs, vue-loader

I am trying to dev-build a **Vue project** with **Webpack**.  As soon as I add `script` tag in the `App.vue` file, I get an error in the browser saying `Unexpected token export`.

```
//App.vue
<template>
    <p style="background-color:blue,">Hello World!</p>
</template>

<!-- works perfectly fine without this script tag -->
<script>
    export default {
        name    : 'app'
    }
</script>

<style>
    h1 {
        color               : white;
        background-color    : darkgreen
    }
</style>
```

The webpack configuration :

```
//webpack.config.js
const HTMLPlugin    = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const webpack       = require('webpack')
//
const BabelLoader = {
    loader  : 'babel',
    test    : /\.js$/,
    exclude : /node_modules/,
    query   : {
        presets : [ 'es2015', 'stage-2'],
        plugins: [ 'transform-runtime' ]
    }
}
const VueLoaderConfig = {
    loader  : 'vue',
    test    : /\.vue$/,
    exclude : /node_module/
}
//
const HTMLPluginConfig      = new HTMLPlugin({
            template    : './src/index.html'
        })
const CommonsChunkConfig    = new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name    : [ 'vendor', 'bootstrap' ]
})
//
const config    = {
    // ENTRY
    entry   : {
        app     : './src/app.js',
        vendor  : [ 'vue' ]
    },  
    // OUTPUT
    output  : {
        filename    : '[name].[chunkhash].js',
        path        : __dirname + '/dist'
    },
    // PLUGINS
    plugins : [
        HTMLPluginConfig,
        CommonsChunkConfig
    ],
    // MODULE
    module  : {
        loaders : [
            BabelLoader,
            VueLoaderConfig
        ]
    }
}
//
module.exports = config
```

The entry point - `app.js`

```
//app.js
import Vue from 'vue'
//
import App from './App.vue'
//
new Vue({
    el          : '#app',
    ...App
})
```

### Note:

- It works perfectly fine until I add the `<script>` tag in the `App.vue` file.

Please advice me what could I be missing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Overall solution :

### 1. install `webpack2` (since some features will not work with webpack-1)

`npm i -D webpack@2.2.0-rc.3`

### 2. in `webpack config`, here are the `loader configs` :

```
const BabelLoaderConfig 
    = {
        loader  : 'babel-loader',
        test    : /\.js$/,
        exclude : /node_modules/,
        query   : {
            presets : [ 'latest', 'stage-2' ]
        }
    }
const VueLoaderConfig 
    = {
        loader  : 'vue-loader',
        test    : /\.vue$/,
        exclude : /node_modules/
    }
```

#### Here's a full list of dependencies in `package.json` -

```
...
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-latest": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.20.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.26.0",
    "vue-loader": "^10.0.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.1.8",
    "webpack": "^2.2.0-rc.3"
  }
  ...
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's because you are using the `stage-2` preset and `export` extensions are part of [stage-1](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-1/) which isn't included in `stage-2`, so you can either use `stage-1`:

`npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-1`

`presets : [ 'es2015', 'stage-1']`

remove the stage presets altogether, or just use `module.exports`.